# Display values from dynamically created input fields - jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, dynamically-generated, input-field

I have jquery piece of code that creates  2 input fields inside div when user clicks "ADD" button.

The script also add uniqe id for each input usernaname and its adress like:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">1</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="username1" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="User name">
  <input type="text" id="adress1" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Adress">
 <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Remove</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

username1 adress1
username2 adress2
username3 adress3
...

How can i "instantly" for each username field create `<div>` with same ID (number) and append username and adress values that match ID, for example:

```
 <div id="result1">
username1(value) <br/>
adress1(value)
</div>
```

Also when i click Remove button (span) how can i delete that username, its adress field and matching result `<div>`and rearange left fields and result  IDs.

I have stuck at this point:
https://jsfiddle.net/ribosed/f0arxw5h/17/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }

    var usernamesDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'usernames' + counter);

    usernamesDiv.after().html('<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">' + counter +
    '</span></div><input type="text" id="username' + counter + '" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Username"> ' +
    '<input type="text" id="adress' + counter + '" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Adress">' + '   <div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Remove</span></div>' +
          '</div>');

    usernamesDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    

    counter++;
    
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }

    counter--;

        $("#username" + counter).remove();


     });

   
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 
   <!-- JS ------jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


 
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding:45px 10px 10px 10px;">



<button type="button"  id='addButton' class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >Add username</button>
<br/>


<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="usernames1">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">1</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="username1" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="User name">
  <input type="text" id="adress1" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Adress">
 <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Remove</span>
  </div>
 
    </div>
</div>





<div>
```

Comment: Did my fully working answer solved the question ?

Comment: Dear AlwaysHelping, thank you very much for the detailed answer.
During the day, I will test your code and let you know the final conclusion as to whether this is what I had planned.

At first glance, it seems like a fantastic improvement. Please give me a few hours to get back to you.

Thanks again for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: No problem -Take your time.  My answer should suffice all your requirements i am sure - but Let me know if i can help you further :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping You did a great job! I tried to further edit your code the way I originally envisioned it even though I didn’t explain it properly at the beginning.
Results are now in one place and I tried to enable the function of deleting inputs and corresponding results div that have the same id. However I am wrong somewhere. I would like to remove the display button so that the script automatically creates the result and performs keyup values ​​of the corresponding inputs into corresponding result div.  I mean, i would like to use instead of click event sometnih like .blur or similar.

Comment: It would be perfect if the script had the ability to correct numbers when i delete input fields that were not last. For example if i have 5 fields and 5 results, and when i delete third it should rearange al fields and its results  in order to have correct numbernig (1,2,3,4 instead of 1,2,4,5). This is the my "updated" version of your code https://jsfiddle.net/ribosed/f0arxw5h/56/

Comment: Than you very much again for your help! Best regards.

Comment: Happy to help - you are asking a complete different question to what was originally posted to this. I provided an answer based on the things mentioned. I would suggest if you can open a new thread with your numbering requirements - that would be great - according to stackoverflow we need a thread if something is different then what was posted originally. I hope you understand :) Would you mind accepting my answer below by clicking the grey check-mark as i have solved the original question for you already.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping of course, you did a fantastic job for me. I will soon post the another thread. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is fully working code for you. There were few things that needed a `change` to be able to work **better** to match your requirement.

To display `each` value `dynamically` below each input box we need to jQuery `$.each` function on both the username and address classes added dynamically to the each input field.

Once we loop through each input available we will check it `attr` which will your `username1` or `address1` for example. As there `id's` added dynamically we need to ensure that we get their value `separately` as well for them to be display in the results section.

I have also simplified your code by of adding new fields input box to the page we can use `append()` function to add new clone `fields` to our div. We just reserve a div where these new fields (a new div) will be display into.

To `remove` a specific added field input group we need to use `event delegation` and add a class to a `remove` button once its created we can .remove function .parent function to be remove the whole `input group` from the page and `decrease` the counter as well.

Lastly, I have added notes to each line of code for your understanding as well

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Counter
  var counter = 2;

  //Add fields
  $("#addButton").click(function() {
    if (counter > 10) {
      alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
      return
    }

    //New field HTML
    var usernamesDiv = ('<div id="usernames' + counter + '"><div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">' + counter +
      '</span></div><input type="text" id="username' + counter + '" class="form-control username" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Username"> ' +
      '<input type="text" id="adress' + counter + '" class="form-control address" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Adress">' + '<div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text removeButton">Remove</span></div>' +
      '</div><div id="results' + counter + '"></div></div>');

    //Append new fields
    $('.newTextBoxes').append(usernamesDiv);

    //Increase the counter
    counter++;

  });

  //Remove clicked field
  $(document).on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
    //Remove clicked feilds
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove(); //remove username parent

    //Decrease the counter
    counter--;
  });


  //Display results / below each input
  $(document).on('click', '#showInputValue', function() {

    //Each username
    var results = '<div id="results">'
    $('.username').each(function(index, element) {
      var getUserAttr = $(element).attr('id')
      var getUserValue = $(element).val()
      var lastChar = getUserAttr.substr(getUserAttr.length - 1);
      var getDiv = $('#results' + lastChar + '')
      var getDiv1 = $('#results' + lastChar + ' .user')
      getDiv1.html('') //empty username
      getDiv.append('<span class="user">' + getUserAttr + '(' + getUserValue + ')<br></span>')
    })


    //Each address
    $('.address').each(function(index, element) {
      var getAddrAttr = $(element).attr('id')
      var getAddrValue = $(element).val()
      var lastChar = getAddrAttr.substr(getAddrAttr.length - 1);
      var getDiv = $('#results' + lastChar + '')
      var getDiv1 = $('#results' + lastChar + ' .addr')
      getDiv1.html('') //empty address
      getDiv.append('<span class="addr">' + getAddrAttr + '(' + getAddrValue + ')</span>')
    })
  })

});
```

```css
.removeButton {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding:45px 10px 10px 10px;">
  <button type="button" id='addButton' class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add username</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="usernames1">
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">1</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="username1" class="form-control username" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="User name">
        <input type="text" id="address1" class="form-control address" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Adress">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text">Remove</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="results1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="newTextBoxes"></div>

    <button type="button" id='showInputValue' class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Display Input Values</button>

    </div>
```